# Creating a multilingual link to a CMS page in Prestashop

Tags: hyperlink, prestashop

I want to make a link to a CMS page in prestashop, the webshop has 3 languages. How do i make the link autoswitch the language?

When you make a cms-page, you can enter the translations for the title of that page. So i have to get that title in the code?

This is what i have now (which stays in English when i switch the language):

```
<a href='{$link->getCMSLink('8', 'about-us')}' title='{l s='About us'}'>{l s='About us'}</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply only pass the id_cms parameter? By providing an alias, you force the dispatcher to use this alias when creating the link.

If you use `{$link->getCMSLink('8')}` Prestashop will get the current language and find the proper alias in that language.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But when i change it to
<a href='{$link->getCMSLink('8')}</a>
I don't get a link in my menu. So i have to change this part:
{l s='About us'}
So the link text changes when you switch language.

Comment: Are you using Prestashop 1.6 or an older version? `{$link->getCMSLink('8')}` works well on my installation.

Comment: Prestashop 1.6. 
So i change it to this? <a href='{$link->getCMSLink('8', 'over-ons', $cookie->id_lang|intval)}' title='{l s='Over ons'}'>{$link->getCMSLink('8')}</a>

This gives me the full URL..  You can check it here http://grafomantestsite.be/nl/ (beneath the HOME link)

Comment: Yes but the second call to `$link` is the right one. If i switch language to French I get `<a href="http://grafomantestsite.be/fr/content/8-over-ons" title="Over ons">http://grafomantestsite.be/fr/content/8-a-propos-de-nous</a>`. The first link doesn't get the good alias, while the second does.

Comment: Okay, so i use <a href='{$link->getCMSLink('8')}'>{$link->getCMSLink('8')}</a> Now how do i get a clean link like 'A propos de nous' instead of '
HTTP://GRAFOMANTESTSITE.BE/NL/CONTENT/8-A-PROPOS-DE-NOUS' ?

Comment: For this you'll have to pass this information from your controller to your template. You can't get a cms name from any template natively.